# Tag Wiki - use of wikipedia appropriate?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

Wikipedia's become fairly ubiquitous, but I'm wondering if it's appropriate for the Wiki *here* --- here's what I'm trying to say:  A moderator just added a few tags which I find very helpful. So I wanted to return the favor and give a Tag wiki description because it is obscure and I happen to feel comfortable in explaining it. Once I started to create the wiki, I realized that the wikipedia entry says it far better and more thoroughly than I ever could.  So is it lame or just bad practice to merely have a link to it in the description?  (My rep's too low to create a tag wiki without it being approved first anyway, but I want to save someone the trouble of out right rejecting because this might be incorrect procedure.) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this Meta Stack Exchange discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000/256282)

While you can quote Wikipedia in tag wikis (but not excerpts) *as long as you attribute it correctly*, it's generally discouraged.

If you're asking about making the tag wiki be little more than just a link to Wikipedia, then don't do that. They should be useful and informative by themselves.